# How can i prevent/reduce bass trapping?

Tags: acoustics, monitors, bass

I have to put my monitors in two corners. What can i do to prevent/reduce bass build up issues?

Answer (score 2):

Some monitors allow you to adjust the bass response for the purpose of corner placement and the like. But since you ask, I suppose yours don't have that feature. See this forum for flush/soffit mounted monitors, corner traps, ceiling clouds, Helmholtz resonators, etc. A lot to take in , but worth it.
http://johnlsayers.com/phpBB2/viewforum.php?f=12&sid=c98229bdc295f3cba261d478c915272f

Answer (score 0):

you can use speakers that have tha bassports in front and allways stick to small cones max 6" if you don't want to treat your room heavily.

Keep close to your speakers so you don't get the volume too high. High volumes result in room excitement.

Keep in mind that everything can count as treatment, bookshelves,couches, glasses(windows etc), open doors/closed doors.

Also try to learn some information about room sizes so you decide where to put your monitors and stuff:) good luck.